pyinstaller export --> cmd opens 1 sec: unable to open database and closes again
When I try to run my Python program, a cmd window opens with this message:
Fehler beim Verbinden zur Datenbank: unable to open database file
Traceback (most recent call last)):
File "StudentcardReaderv1.01.py", line 19, in <module>
File "database_01.py", line 23, in create_table

AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'c'
[10480]Failed to execute script 'StudentcardReaderV1.01' due to unhandled exception!

After about a millisecond cmd closes and nothing happens.
I export my program using the line: pyinstaller StudentcardReaderv1.01.py database_01.py --onefile
# main.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import database_01
from datetime import datetime
import os

# Verzeichnis, in dem sich die Python-Skriptdateien befinden
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Pfad zur Datenbankdatei
db_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'databases', 'students.db')


# Gui
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Studentcard Reader v1.01")
root.geometry("800x400")
db = database_01.Database(db_path)
db.create_table()

# Maincode


root.mainloop()

# database_01.py

import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.conn = None
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
            self.c = self.conn.cursor()
            self.create_table()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("Fehler beim Verbinden zur Datenbank:", e)

    def close_connection(self):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()



    # Maincode

I tried changing the relative directionary to the program's folder.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Thanks for trimming your code. Can you still reproduce the error? After all, you removed create_table from your code. Could you also clarify where you struggle? The error message pretty much tells you the exact line where things go wrong and why.

databases\students.db does not exist inside the temporary directory created when the generated executable is executed.  So the line self.c = self.conn.cursor() inside Database.__init__() will not be executed because exception is raised when self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file) is executed.  Therefore self.c does not exists when db.create_table() is executed in the main application.

Note that even the database file can be created, it will be lost after the executable is terminated because it is created inside the temporary directory which will be removed after the program exits.
